# line! Famo.us -- Can someone explain what means: "Your number in line is" >70K

Tags: famo.us

A week ago I was excited by the rollout of the famo.us (HTML5/javascript) framework.
I eagerly signed up for access.

Ever since then, when I sign into the famo.us site, 
I am shown a mysterious page tell me "Your number in line is:"
... followed by some seemingly random number between 70K and 80K.

WTF?

BTW, I have downloaded everything in the famo.us account on github.com.
I put about 30 minutes perusing the code before I started to feel 
I was not using my time efficiently, 
and I shouldn't have to work this hard.
Am I just being a bad lazy noob? 
Am I missing something?
I want more guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Famo.us is slowly rolling out their Famo.us University and you will have to wait to get in. However.. Famo.us University is not that complete right now and you will learn more just by running the examples. The documentation is no more than what is in the source code and neither are the guides..

So go to..

https://github.com/Famous/examples/tree/master/src/examples

And check out each of the examples.. It is where I learned the most.

You simply link the example file in main.js

eg.

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  // choose your test here
  require('src/examples/core/Surface/true-sizing.js');
});
```

I know it's tough, with no community but you just got to hammer through it!

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes! In recommandeer starting with the guides, then viewing THE examples, then Reading the source code. Try to creatie little experiments to play with concepts. You need to be an experienced programmer to do this, otherwise you'll have to wait until you get into famous university for a more beginner introduction.

Comment: @markmarijnissen Thanks for the reply Mark! I had really hit a WallTransition before I found the examples ;) Especially that true-sizing feature, That was a little hard to find!

Comment: Oh yes indeed! There are some little secrets not easily found when reading source code! I knew this one though, guess I picked it up somewhere

Comment: Thanks. Just knowing I am not missing something obvious makes me feel better.